# Translate curl PUT commandline to requests

Tags: curl, python-requests

Following works fine on commandline

```
curl -L -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Name: Joe" -d "{\"Age\": 64, \"City\": \"Seattle\"}"
 "https://localhost:8080/add"
```

I translated to requests as below but it fails with authentication error.

```
  headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Name' : 'Joe'}
  data = {'Age': 64, 'City':'Seattle'}
  r = requests.put("https://localhost:8080/add", data=data, headers=headers)
```

Would appreciate help in spotting any obvious error in my translation. Thanks

Comment: It seems there is no authentication field in your request. The 'Name' is not for authentication, right?

Comment: Can you assume the I have the 'authentication' field instead of 'name' in both examples?

Comment: Then I think the translation is right. You might want to do it like `requests.put(..., auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))`

Comment: Another possible try is `import simplejson as json` then pass the data as string like `data = json.dumps({...})`